# tlsv1 alert insufficient security with rabbitmq

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

Tried with management console with both openssl and browser after enable ssl with rabbitMq 3.4.3.1 (Erlang 17.1)

Got this insufficient security issue. I guess something issue with erlang accepted ciphers for negotiation?

Anyone see this?

Comment: any updates? @shaozhen. How did u resolve this? I am too facing this issue.

Answer (score 3):

My problem with same appearance was in x509 `keyUsage` certificate extension. Documentation ["highly recommends" to use both digitalSignature and keyEncipherment](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#key-usage-effects-on-cipher-suites), but in practice rabbitmq (3.7.18) won't work with RSA certificate specifying only `keyUsage=keyEncipherment`. You have to either omit `keyUsage` or add `digitalSignature`.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the exact message you're seeing (e.g. a snippet from the log). You can specify [allowed TLS versions and ciphers](https://gist.github.com/michaelklishin/20282d4280d7b6671f70).

See also "Disabling SSL/TLS Versions via Configuration" and "Known TLS Vulnerabilities: POODLE, BEAST, etc" in the [TLS documentation guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html).

Answer (score 0):

Indeed certificate key usage extensions can also be the root cause. RabbitMQ documentation now has note about this [1].

1. https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#key-usage